# Assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast error in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, web-crawler

I am building a C tool which will search for all the  attributes in a XML file and use curl to crawl them and check if they return 404 error or if they are working.

All modules of my code are working good so far, except that when I try to store the list of fetched URLs in the  urlStack variable I get this warning:

```
crawler.c: In function ‘locXMl’:
crawler.c:119:34: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  119 |             urlStack[stackIndex] = regSearch("<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>",fileData);
```

When I run the compiled file, I get the segmentation fault error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>


int statusCode(char *addr);
char* regSearch(char* regPattern, char* hayStack);
char locXMl(char* fileName, char* urlStack );

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* urlStack[] = {};
    
    //checking if the file name is specified
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("\nMissing file name.\n");
        return 1;
    } //else continue


    //checking if the file exsits
    FILE *file;
    if((file = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL )
        {
            printf("\nSpecified file does not exist\n");
            printf("\n%s\n",argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }

    //build the list of URLs in urlStack
    locXMl(argv[1],*urlStack);


}



int statusCode(char *addr){

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    long response_code;

    // Initialize curl
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    // Create a curl handle
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, addr);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res == CURLE_OK) {

            curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    // Cleanup global curl resources
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return  response_code;

}



/* Use regex to get matching url from the XML */

char* regSearch(char* regPattern, char* hayStack) {
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char *string = hayStack;
    char *pattern = regPattern;
    regmatch_t match;

    // Compile the regular expression
    reti = regcomp(&regex, pattern, 0);
    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
     
    }

    // Execute the regular expression
    reti = regexec(&regex, string, 1, &match, 0);
    //print the found match
    if (!reti) {

        return string;

    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
            // do something if the match is not found
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex execution failed\n");
        
    }

    // Free the compiled regular expression
    regfree(&regex);

   
}


/* get all the URLs from within the loc element in XML */
char locXMl(char* fileName, char* urlStack ){

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(fileName,"r");  
    char fileData[100];

    int stackIndex = 0;

    while(fgets(fileData, 100, fptr)) {

        if(regSearch("<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>",fileData)){

            urlStack[stackIndex] = regSearch("<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>",fileData);
            stackIndex++;
           //printf("%s\n",  regSearch("<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>",fileData));
        }

    }
   
}
```

I tried changing the way how urlStack variable is declared but the issue persists. Expecting to put all the URLs in that variable as an array.

Comment: To start with `char locXMl(char* fileName, char* urlStack ){` --> `char locXMl(char* fileName, char** urlStack ){` and then fix the way you call the function

Comment: `char* urlStack` is a single pointer. `urlStack[stackIndex]` is a single character. You need to pass an array of pointers to the function in order to assign like that, which you would have if you removed the `*` here `locXMl(argv[1],*urlStack);`.

Comment: I don't use C regex enough to know if it is an issue, but the return in `regSearch` skips the `regfree(&regex);` line and the function does not return a value at all in the failure case. I'd assume you would want to return `NULL`.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I am getting this error:
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @genx yep... How many elements does this array have `char* urlStack[] = {};` ? What will happen when `stackIndex` becomes e.g. 42

Comment: @SupportUkraine This is an empty array at the start, the number of elements are not fixed and can change depending on the supplied XML file. I want to use this array to store the fetched URLs from the XML

Comment: @genx hmm... and what makes the array grow in size?

Comment: @SupportUkraine The while loop in the locXML function, which is reading from a file using fptr, and searching for the regex URL using regSearch, if a match is found that gets stored in the urlStack.

Comment: @genx Hint: Can an array in C ever change size?

Comment: @SupportUkraine I assigned it dynamically without a fixed size like this:
char* urlStack[] = {};

Comment: @genx In other languages than C arrays (or similar type like C++ vector) may grow in size at runtime as new elements are added. But in C that can't be done. So you definition sets a fixed size... for fun try: `char* urlStack[1000] = {};` and see what happens.

Comment: @genx BTW: What you do is not dynamic allocation. Dynamic allocation is more like `char* urlStack = malloc(...)`

Comment: @SupportUkraine I tried what you asked, very interesting the message did disappear. I tried running the program and looping on the urlStack to printf and surprisingly the data within it is filled with gibrish , some even which does not match the regex  and segmentation fault at end:
like
<!-- XML Sitemap generat+���Km�e�
  
Note: Regex code is working fine, if I printf within the loop (the commented code) it shows correct data.

Let me try malloc now

Comment: The no of elements I have are unknown, I can use malloc only with known no of elements @SupportUkraine

Comment: Well, the way you handle that is to use `realloc` to allocate more space as you need it. As for why your array might contain garbage it could be that you are accessing the array beyond the number of items you've assigned to it and you're accessing uninitialized elements or you need to make a copy of the data you need rather than having a dangling pointer to a local variable that has gone out of scope.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You are right, it was a problem with my approach, strcpy seems to help to an extent, rest I will figure out.

Comment: Thanks to @SupportUkraine and RetiredNinja, this issue is now solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code according to answer provided by @SupportUkraine as follows, and this solved the specific problem I mentioned here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int statusCode(char *addr);
char* regSearch(char* regPattern, char* hayStack);
char** locXMl(char* fileName, char** urlStack );

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* urlStack[1000];
    
    //checking if the file name is specified
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("\nMissing file name.\n");
        return 1;
    } //else continue


    //checking if the file exsits
    FILE *file;
    if((file = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL )
        {
            printf("\nSpecified file does not exist\n");
            printf("\n%s\n",argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    fclose(file);    

    //build the list of URLs in urlStack
   char** data =  locXMl(argv[1],urlStack);
    
    printf("%s",urlStack[10]);
    


}



int statusCode(char *addr){

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    long response_code;

    // Initialize curl
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    // Create a curl handle
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, addr);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res == CURLE_OK) {

            curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    // Cleanup global curl resources
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return  response_code;

}



/* Use regex to get matching url from the XML */

char* regSearch(char* regPattern, char* hayStack) {
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char *string = hayStack;
    char *pattern = regPattern;
    regmatch_t match;

    // Compile the regular expression
    reti = regcomp(&regex, pattern, 0);
    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
     
    }

    // Execute the regular expression
    reti = regexec(&regex, string, 1, &match, 0);
    //print the found match
    if (!reti) {

        regfree(&regex);
        return string;

    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
            // do something if the match is not found
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex execution failed\n");
        
    }

    // Free the compiled regular expression
    regfree(&regex);

   
}


/* get all the URLs from within the loc element in XML */
char** locXMl(char* fileName, char** urlStack ){

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(fileName,"r");  
    char fileData[100];

    int stackIndex = 0;

    while(fgets(fileData, 100, fptr)) {

        if(regSearch("<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>",fileData)){

            urlStack[stackIndex] = strcat(regSearch("<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>",fileData), "");
            //printf("%s\n",urlStack[stackIndex]);
            stackIndex++;
         
        }

    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return urlStack;
   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an extra asterisk in the declaration:

`char locXMl(char* fileName, char** urlStack );`

And no asterisk when you call it:

`locXMl(argv[1],urlStack);`

And of course you have to allocate space for all those pointers in `urlStack`.

You will also get warnings about non-void functions that don't return a value, and about passing a string constant as a non-const char*. But you didn't ask about them.

Comment: *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

I have modified the code to close the file at bottom as well.